# How to use the kubectl apply -f filename command in windows minikube

Tags: windows, kubernetes, apply, kubectl, minikube

I'm new to Kubernetes and have installed minikube in my Windows 11 machine. I want to create a kubernetes configuration file say **nginx-deployment.yaml** and create my deployment using that configuration file.

In Mac OS, the nginx-deployment.yaml file is created using the **touch nginx-deployment.yaml** command. How to do the same from Windows cmd prompt as touch command won't work?

Also, is it possible to create the nginx-deployment.yaml file in any directory in Windows and specify the path to that directory in the **kubectl apply -f path-to-the-configuration-file\filename.yaml** command?

[image: the thing I want to replicate in windows minikube]

Comment: This question is not about Kubernetes and not about programming. It's about creating a file in windows. You can create a file in any editor. If you want to create an empty file in a shell, you can, for example, write `echo "" > nginx-deployment.yaml `

Comment: @Abhijit is your issue resolved if you are still facing some issues revert back so that we can help you..

Comment: Hi, I'll check on this. I have been a bit busy over the past week so was unable to check. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @Abhijit have you got any chance to go through my solution revert back if you are still facing some issues

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways for creating a file using CMD in windows, while using echo is one way(as mentioned by  `Eran`), there are multiple ways to create a file in windows as mentioned [here](https://cmdwindows.com/create-file).

Once you have created your file you can pass the path to your kubectl command, similar to  linux. However, the path syntax will vary here for example

```
kubectl apply -f C:\Users\yourUsername\path\to\file.yaml
```